# How to remove double backslash from each element of a vector?

Tags: r, vector, cat

I have a vector containing a bunch of file paths, like this:

```
 v <- paste0("D:\\file\\path", 1:3)
```

I want to replace all the double backslashes with just a single backslash. So the output would look like this:

```
"D:\file\path1" "D:\file\path2" "D:\file\path3"
```

I tried this:

```
sapply(df, cat)
```

However this just generates a list of NULL values. I also tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    v[i] <- cat(v[i])
}
```

But this gives an error: replacement has zero lengths. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The string `"D:\\file\\path"` doesn't really have double slashes. If you do `cat("D:\\file\\path")` you can see what's *really* here. It's just what when working with strings, the slash is an escape character to it needs to be escaped when you literally want that value to appear. It doesn't actually count as an extra character in the string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "what's really here." When I print the vector, it shows the double slashes. Eventually need this to write the vector to an excel sheet--are you saying that when I do so, the double slashes will be automatically made into single slashes?

Comment: The `print()` function escapes characters that need to be escaped so it doesn't dump malformed data to the console. The `cat()` function does not do that. If you were to write those values out to disk, you would see they would also not have the double slashed there. Just look at the character counts for `nchar("\\")`. There's just one character (slash) there.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `\` is an escape character in R, thus replacing `\\` by `\` will cause wrong interpretation from R.

If the need is for paths, use the `/` character instead of `\\`:

```
v <- gsub(v, pattern="\\", replacement="/", fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: what if it's not for a path?

Comment: @Nakx, you can double each backslash (escaping the backslash with a bakslash), try : `print("\\\\") # "\\" `